# Search and replace in Richtextbox - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a richtextbox that I want to search and replace only WHOLE words.

I have some code, however I have a feeling the way I have done it may not allow whole words only.

CODE:

```
    Dim search As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim replace1 As String = TextBox2.Text

    Dim input As String

    input = Form1.RichTextBox1.Text.Trim

    Dim location As Integer

    search = search.Trim()
    replace1 = replace1.Trim()
    location = input.IndexOf(search)

    If location = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Text not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")
    Else
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = input.Remove(location, search.Length).Insert(location, replace1)
        MsgBox("Text " & search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, , )
    End If
```

If you have another way of doing it please share.

Second attempt: Now works, however I want only whole words to be found.

```
 Dim search As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim replace1 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim input As String
    input = Form1.RichTextBox1.Text.Trim
    search = search.Trim()
    replace1 = replace1.Trim()


    If Regex.IsMatch(input, search) = True Then

        Dim out As String = Regex.Replace(input, search, replace1)
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = out

        MsgBox(search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    Else

        MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")
    End If
```

FINAL CODE:

```
   Dim search As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim replace1 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim input As String
    input = Form1.RichTextBox1.Text.Trim
    search = search.Trim()
    replace1 = replace1.Trim()


    If Regex.IsMatch(input, " " & search & " ") = True Then

        Dim out As String = Regex.Replace(input, " " & search & " ", " " & replace1 & " ")
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = out

        MsgBox(search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        GoTo line

    Else
        GoTo line3

        MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")

    End If
line3:

    If Regex.IsMatch(input, search & " ") = True Then

        Dim out As String = Regex.Replace(input, search & " ", replace1 & " ")
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = out

        MsgBox(search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        GoTo line

    Else
        GoTo line2
        MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")

    End If
line2:

    If Regex.IsMatch(input, " " & search) = True Then

        Dim out As String = Regex.Replace(input, " " & search, " " & replace1)
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = out

        MsgBox(search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        GoTo line
    Else

        MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")
        GoTo line
    End If





line:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern = "\b" + Regex.Escape(search) + "\b";

if (Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success) {
  // found it
  Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace1);
}
```

The \b indicates a word boundary. It will match words that come directly after punctuation and spaces, or appear at the beginning of the string...

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: First I am doing this in VB.Net ... so this is the code I put, however it always goes to the else:


        Dim pattern As String = vbBack & Regex.Escape(search) & vbBack


        If Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success Then

            Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace1)

        Else

            MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")
        End If

Comment: Ok I edited it with this code... However how can I make it only accept whole words? 
        'If Regex.IsMatch(input, search) = True Then

            Dim out As String = Regex.Replace(input, search, replace1)
            Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = out

            MsgBox(search & " has been replaced with " & replace1, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        Else

            MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Not Found")
        End If'

Comment: OK i couldn't get the "\b" to work but i edited the orginal with my final code that works well.